# Inserting variables into JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow plugin, but I'm trying to add a few variables to the strings written below, but I can't.

```
var data= {
    "drawflow": {
        "Home": {
            "data": {}
        },
        "Other": {
            "data": {
                "16": {
                    "id": 16,
                    "name": "Michael",
                    "data": {},
                    "class": "michael"                  
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to do  but I can't add my variables is there any other way;
Unexpected token gives '+' error when I add it as "'" + variable+ "'"

```
var int= 2;
var string="car";

"data": {
                int: {
                    "id": int,
                    "name": string,
                    "data": {},
                    "class": string,                
                    "inputs": {}
                }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code which gives the error?

Comment: JSON is a string; this is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Are you trying to use your variable `int` as the key here? If so, you'll need to use bracket notation. [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Regarding `Error:Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element':` that you mention below: that seems unrelated to this. Where are you calling `querySelectorAll()`?

Answer (score -1):

You could use string interpolation like so:

```
var int= 2;
var string="car";

"data": {
                int: {
                    "id": `${int}`,
                    "name": `${string},
                    "data": {},
                    "class": `${string}`,                
                    "inputs": {}
                }
```

the special quotes `` make it so you can insert variables with ${}